# Get Previous Row but using Date, rather than Primary

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2017

I've got the below example data, and for each "Person" identifier, I'm trying to show the field valuese for the latest Row (EffectiveTo=NULL), and the one before it.

How could this be done while not having a primary key with the data to use?

Expected Output is:

[image]

[image]

```
Create Table #temp
(
    Person int,
    Amount money,
    DailyAmount money,
    EffectiveFrom datetime,
    EffectiveTo datetime NULL
)

insert into #temp
(
    Person,
    Amount,
    DailyAmount,
    EffectiveFrom,
    EffectiveTo
)
select
    1,
    450,
    64.28,
    '2018-03-15 00:00:00.000',
    '2020-06-17 00:00:00.000'
union all
select
    1,
    500,
    71.42,
    '2020-05-22 00:00:00.000',
    '2020-06-18 00:00:00.000'
union all
select
    1,
    93.75,
    13.39,
    '2020-06-19 00:00:00.000',
    NULL    
union all
select
    2,
    200,
    28.57,
    '2019-02-05 00:00:00.000',
    '2020-01-02 00:00:00.000'
union all
select
    2,
    300,
    42.85,
    '2020-01-03 00:00:00.000',
    NULL    

select * from #temp
```

Comment: Post your expected output as well

Comment: Sure @ArunPalanisamy, posted a screenshot - thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `LEAD() OVER ()` window function to get previous rows data

```
WITH mydata
AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY person ORDER BY EffectiveFrom DESC) rn,
              LEAD(amount) OVER (PARTITION BY person ORDER BY EffectiveFrom DESC) Prev_amount, 
              LEAD(DailyAmount) OVER (PARTITION BY person ORDER BY EffectiveFrom DESC) Prev_DailyAmount, 
              LEAD(EffectiveFrom) OVER (PARTITION BY person ORDER BY EffectiveFrom DESC) Prev_Eff_From, 
              LEAD(EffectiveTo) OVER (PARTITION BY person ORDER BY EffectiveFrom DESC) Prev_Eff_To
    FROM #temp
    )
SELECT Person, Amount, DailyAmount, EffectiveFrom, EffectiveTo, Prev_amount, Prev_DailyAmount, Prev_Eff_From, Prev_Eff_To
FROM mydata
WHERE rn = 1
```

[***Check Demo Here***](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2392c3a8627edd3a78ae237e5b3cef1d)